# C Makefile with two executables and a common directory

Tags: c, makefile

I need to make a makefile which compiles two executables, **cassini** and **saturnd**

I've been having a ton of problems with this makefile I'm using. Sometimes it compiles, sometimes not.

Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing -I include
SRCCASSINI = $(wildcard src/cassini/*.c)
SRCSATURND = $(wildcard src/saturnd/*.c)
SRCCOMMON = $(wildcard src/common/*.c)
OBJCASSINI = $(SRCCASSINI:.c=.o)
OBJSATURND = $(SRCSATURND:.c=.o)
OBJCOMMON = $(SRCCOMMON:.c=.o)
EXEC = cassini saturnd

all: objs $(EXEC)

objs: $(OBJCOMMON)

cassini : $(OBJCASSINI)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJCASSINI) $(OBJCOMMON)

saturnd : $(OBJSATURND) objs
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJSATURND) $(OBJCOMMON)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

clean : 
    rm -f src/*/*.o $(EXEC)

distclean : 
    rm -f src/*/*/.o $(EXEC)
```

Project structure

- Include dir:

  `include` contains the `.h` files of all `c` files and more.
- SRC dir:

  SRC contains 3 directories:

1. `cassini*` contains all source files that should be compiled **only with the cassini executable**
2. `saturnd` contains all source files that should be compiled **only with the saturnd executable**
3. `common` contains all source files that should be compiled **with both cassini and saturnd**

Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/26brtpq

`make` will fill my screen with verbose output. Sometimes it compiles, sometimes not. For some reason.

Comment: Please describe the `"ton of problems"` more clearly and include the error messages and output from `make` as text verbatim.

Comment: undefined behavior, varies, usually undefined references. for example : /usr/bin/ld: saturnd.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `req_fifo'

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Without access to the actual code, we have no way to know what `req_fifo` is or how the compiler is supposed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kinds of problems, specifically, you see it's hard to say for sure.  But, one issue is your `cassini` target doesn't list any of the common objects as prerequisites.  That means when `cassini` is linked it might be using older, not-recompiled versions of the object files (or they might be missing altogether).

You should change your link targets to this:

```
cassini : $(OBJCASSINI) $(OBJCOMMON)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

saturnd : $(OBJSATURND) $(OBJCOMMON)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

and see if that works better.  If that doesn't help then your makefile looks correct so it must be something you haven't shown us here, and the only way to help with that is to see exactly how you invoke make and some explicit errors; as mentioned above please don't attach, or link to, screenshots: instead edit your question and cut and paste the text, with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to use a makefile. I've been programming for *years* and still can't reliably make one of those do what I want.

Instead, you use [cmake](https://cmake.org/). It has an easy syntax which you can mostly copy-paste from one project to another and generates makefiles which reliably Do The Right Thing™.

To use cmake, you make a file called `CMakeLists.txt` in the parent directory of `src`. Put this in the file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)

project(cassini_saturn LANGUAGES C)

SET(common_files
  src/common/g.c
  src/common/h.c
  src/common/i.c
)

add_executable(cassini
  src/cassini/a.c
  src/cassini/b.c
  src/cassini/c.c
  ${common_files}
)
target_compile_features(cassini PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(cassini PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing)
target_include_directories(cassini PRIVATE include)

add_executable(saturnd
  src/saturnd/d.c
  src/saturnd/e.c
  src/saturnd/f.c
  ${common_files}
)
target_compile_features(saturnd PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(saturnd PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing)
target_include_directories(saturnd PRIVATE include)
```

Edit the obvious places so that the files your project uses are each listed individually. It is a best practice to list all the files, rather than relying on wildcards and globs, though if you want to not follow best practices you can use, eg:

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/common/*.c)
```

Now that your `CMakeLists.txt` file is set up, it's time to use it. To do so, you'll run the following:

```sh
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..
make
```

You make a directory called `build` (it could be named anything) to contain all the byproducts of building and compiling your project. That way, you can just `rm -rf build/` to get a clean slate. This is called an out-of-source build and it is a best practice.

The line

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..
```

generates a makefile for your project that, when run, will build your project with optimizations and debugging info. Other options are `Release` (all optimizations, no debugging info) and `Debug` (no optimizations, debugging info).

The final line, `make`, runs the generated makefile and builds the executables inside the `build` directory.

Comment: This is quite dubious. It's not hard to understand `make`, though `cmake` is of course a more modern tool.

Comment: Hey ! Really appreciate this, will use on my personal projects (hate make). But for this, I am required to use make...

Comment: @tripleee second that. My experience is that developers who can't formulate how their software is constructed easily fall victims of any so small change in preconditions, mainly when there is interface functionality beyond an ABI, which very often there is when pulling from huge libs or frameworks. Software construction is, today more than ever, a software engineering discipline as much as writing application code. "use this build system, you won't notice that its there" is bad advice, especially for compiled languages.